# What is a Distasteful Word™?

Tags: word-property

Here are some words that are Distasteful™:

- Many
- Text
- How
- Doors
- Colors
- Fraction

On the other hand, here are some Tasteful™ words:

- Arrows
- Objects
- Stack
- Going
- Free
- Part
- Much

Finally, here are some Tasteless™ words, which are an exception to the rule:

- Puzzler
- Of
- What

Can you figure out what about a word decides if I call it Distasteful™, Tasteful™, or Tasteless™?

Comment: Interesting fresh twist.

Comment: @Matsmath I see what you did there ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distasteful Words are those which

> appear in the titles of your downvoted questions.

Likewise, Tasteful Words are those which

> appear in the titles of your upvoted questions.

And Tasteless Words

> appear in both.

Comment: I have to say there a few too many distasteful words...

Comment: ...How did you figure this out?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 The answerer looked at my profile.